# Issue with Kingfisher in Xcode11 - Could not find module 'Kingfisher' for target 'armv7-apple-ios'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode11, kingfisher

Using Kingfisher 5.7.1, I am unable to import Kingfisher for one class only -  a `UIImageView` extension.

I can build for generic iOS device but if I try on a simulator or a device I get an import error.

I am able to import in another class but one still gives errors every time.

[image: Building for device]

[image: Building for simulator]

I have tried de-integrating Pods and re-installing. Deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, restarting computer. I still run into same issue.

```
import Foundation
import Kingfisher

extension UIImageView {

    public func setImageKF(usingURL url:URL) {
        self.kf.setImage(with: url)
    }

    func layoutImageShadow (shadowImg:UIImageView) {       
        snp.makeConstraints { (maker) in
            maker.top.right.equalToSuperview().offset(1)
            maker.width.height.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Kingfisher podspec file](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/master/Kingfisher.podspec), it has some minimum deployment targets:

```
  s.ios.deployment_target = "10.0"
  s.tvos.deployment_target = "10.0"
  s.osx.deployment_target = "10.12"
  s.watchos.deployment_target = "3.0"
```

It means that this pod won't run in [armv7 devices (iPhone 3GS, 4, 4s, 5, 5c)](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/ARMv7) that can't run iOS 10.0.

It will also not run in i386 simulators that emulate 32 bits armv7 devices.

If you try running on a arm64 build configuration, there is a more straightforward error message:

> Compiling for iOS 9.0, but module 'Kingfisher' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 10.0:

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem in 2022 now, I am using Cocoapods/Xcode 13.2.1/Swift 5 . I finally get it solved by:
1 Select Pods.xcodeproj in Xcode.
2 Switch target to Kingfisher,
3 Change Deployment Info -> iOS 14.0

Answer (score 0):

I Suddenly got this error for my Import Statement, it wasn't There before in My Project.
Error has gone after **Clean & Build The Project**